# How to set the size of the images in the Carousel:

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have been trying to set the size of the images to same value. I need all the images to appear in the same size(Same height and width). The following is the code for the Carousel. All the images appear in their original sizes. How do I go about achieving this?

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images\banner.jpg"   alt="Chania">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images\banner_1.jpg" alt="Chania" >
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images\banner_2.png" alt="Flower">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images\banner_3.jpg" alt="Flower">
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The CSS code I am using is:

```
<style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width:   70%;
      height:  40%;   
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: Just try setting the width. remove the height constraint from your css

Comment: @nevermore. I removed it to see no change. Any other advise? Thanks

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle withe your code. That would help.

Comment: can you provide a working example

Comment: @Molarosa, I am not sure how to create a jsfiddle. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: @Pramod just use this site [jsfiddle.net]

Comment: @hunzaboy, thanks for the time. I don't have any other example from my other project that is working.

Comment: Assign a class to your <img> tag and add your desired height to the same. It should work

Comment: @Nevermore. I created a new class for IMG tag and set the Height property. But the height remain as they were. Not sure how to sort this out.

Comment: Check if your carousel height is statically set.

Comment: @Nevermore, thanks for your time and advise. It got fixed at last by using CSS. How do I vote your answer?

Comment: I believe you solved it by yourself. So, give yourself a pat on your back :)

Comment: @Nevermore, thanks. I moved on, now working on Magento.